# Is there a word that can describe someone who says a lot but takes no action?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions

I know that "doer" is used to describe a person who does things rather than thinking or talking about them. Is there any word opposite to "doer" that can describe someone who verbally protests something but never takes action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about blowhard or bloviator?

Comment: This would be improved with some dictionary definitions of the suggested words.

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm, this is basically trying to find some single words for "all talk and no walk" - certainly no shortage of phrases, but as for single words:

Here are my suggestions (I'll continue to add as they come to mind):

- Charlatan
- Sciolist

This question is similar to [Looking for a word to describe a person who is all talk and no action](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419840/looking-for-a-word-to-describe-a-person-who-is-all-talk-and-no-action). Use this for further reference.

Comment: Your suggestions do not seem to be relevant. **sciolist**, n. (an exceptionally rare word, that few native speakers would know or be able to pronounce.)  *(A person whose knowledge is only superficial, esp. one who makes much of it; a pretender to learning.* ++ **charlatan** * a person falsely claiming to have a special knowledge or skill.*